# How to raise component label position vertically?

Tags: circuitikz

How to raise component label position vertically? L1 label should be a bit higher. I can add new node and specify position - but perhaps exist some label property like "text yshift"? Would be simpler.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt, varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,europeaninductors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}[european, scale=1]
        
        % \wfrac - trupmena su didesniais vertikaliais tarpais 
        \newcommand{\wfrac}[2]{\frac{\vrule width 0px depth 3px\relax #1}{\vrule width 0px height 8px\relax #2}}
    
        
        \draw (0,0) coordinate(point0) to[R=$\wfrac{R_1}{15,75\;K\Omega}$, *-] (0,4) coordinate(point1);
        
        \draw (0,4) to[american inductor, l=$\wfrac{L_1}{15,75\;mH}$, *-*] (4,4) coordinate(point2);
        
        \draw (4,4) to[american inductor=$L_2$] (4,0);
        
        \draw (0,0) to[short, -*] (4,0);
        
        \draw (4,4) to[C=$C_2$] (8,4) coordinate(point3);
        
        \draw (8,4) to[R=$R_2$] (8,0);
        
        \draw (4,0) to[short, -*] (8,0);
        
        \ctikzset{wiper end arrow={Latex[width=4pt]}}
        \draw (11,0) to[pR=$R_3$, mirror, name=R3, *-] (11,4) coordinate(point4);
        \draw (R3.wiper) -- ++ (0,1) -- (11,3) node[circ]{};
        
        \draw (8,0) -- (11,0);
        
        \draw (11,4) to[short, *-*] (8,4);
        
        \draw (0,4) -- (0,6) to[C=$C_1$] (11,6) -- (11,4);
        
        
        \draw (point1) -- ++ (-2,0);
        \draw (point0) -- ++ (-2,0);
        \draw (point4) -- ++ (2,0);
        \draw (11,0) -- ++ (2,0);
        
        
        \node[draw,rectangle,text centered,font=\bfseries] at ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] point1){1};
        \node[draw,rectangle,text centered,font=\bfseries] at ([yshift=0.5cm] point2){2};
        \node[draw,rectangle,text centered,font=\bfseries] at ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm] point4){3};
        \node[draw,rectangle,text centered,font=\bfseries] at (0,-0.5){4};
        \node[draw,rectangle,text centered,font=\bfseries] at (11,-0.5){4};
        
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- Distance of element label you can define with `label distance = <value>`, in MWE below see code line marked by  `% <-------`.
- Your sheme I redraw from scratch. At this:

  - scheme is drawn in four loops
  - I use relative coordinates,
  - some coordinates also contain labels with their names (p0, p1, ...),
  - for labels in coordinates is defined common style
- By this the code of scheme is much shorter and concise:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[americaninductor, europeanresistor,
            siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[every label/.style = {label distance=2mm,
                                             draw, minimum size=1em, inner sep=1pt}]
    \ctikzset{capacitors/width=0.1, capacitors/height=0.5}
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate[label=below:4]   (p0) 
                to[R=$\mfrac{R_1}{\qty{15,75}{\kilo\ohm}}$, *-] ++ (0,4) coordinate[label=above left:1]  (p1)  to[L=$\mfrac{L_1}{\qty{15,75}{\milli\henry}}$, 
                   label distance=5pt,              % <-------
                   *-*] ++ (3, 0) coordinate[label=above:2] (p2)
                to[L=$L_2$, -*]             ++ (0,-4)
        (p2)    to[C=$C_2$, -*]             ++ (3, 0) coordinate (aux1)
                to[R=$R_2$, -*]             ++ (0,-4) 
        (aux1)  to[short, -*]               ++ (3, 0) coordinate[label=above right:3] (p3)
                to[short,-*]                ++ (0,-1) coordinate (aux2)
                to[pR=$R_3$, n=pot]         ++ (0,-2)                
                to[short,-*]                ++ (0,-1) coordinate[label=below:4]   (p4) 
        (aux2)  -|  (pot.wiper)
         (p4)   to[short]   (p0) 
%                          
        (p1)    -- ++ (0,2) to[C=$C_1$]     ++ (9, 0)
                to[short,-*]                ++ (0,-2)
%
        (p1) -- ++ (-2,0) 
        (p0) -- ++ (-2,0) 
        (p3) -- ++ (2,0)
        (p4) -- ++ (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

- Values `\qty{15,75}{\kilo\ohm}` and `\qty{15,75}{\milli\henry}` can be written also in shorten form `\qty{15,75}{\kohm}` and `\qty{15,75}{\mH}` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want the line there? It's the first time I've seen it... otherwise, you can use the stacked label facility. I put comments in the code explaining what I'm doing

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Use siunitx for the values of components
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
% Set the style of your circuit in the preamble for consistency
% here: european symbols, but american inductors (I agree ;-)!)
% stacked labels are centered by default
\ctikzset{european, american inductors, l2 halign=c}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % the horizontal stacked label must be bottom aligned (default is centered) vertically
    \draw(0,0) to[L, l2=$L_1$ and \qty{15.75}{\mH}, l2 valign=b] ++(3,0)
        to [R, l2=$R_1$ and \qty{15.75}{\kohm}] ++ (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the line, you can use the following (again, the change will be for all the document; every stacked label will follow. You need a similar thing for annotation, if you like it).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Use siunitx for the values of components
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
% Set the style of your circuit in the preamble for consistency
% here: european symbols, but american inductors (I agree ;-)!)
% stacked labels are centered by default
\ctikzset{european, american inductors, l2 halign=c}
%%
%% Add a line between entries in stacked labels
%% (and a bit of breathing space)
%%
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{l2base/.code n args={2}{
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/circuitikz/bipole/label/name=%
        \bgroup
        \def\arraystretch{1.2}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
        \def\pgfcirc@ltwo@tabu{\tabular[\pgfcirc@ltwo@valign]}%
        \expandafter\pgfcirc@ltwo@tabu\expandafter{\pgfcirc@ltwo@halign}%
        #1\\ \hline #2%
        \endtabular
        \egroup
    }%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % the horizontal stacked label must be bottom aligned (default is centered) vertically
    \draw(0,0) to[L, l2=$L_1$ and \qty{15.75}{\mH}, l2 valign=b] ++(3,0)
        to [R, l2=$R_1$ and \qty{15.75}{\kohm}] ++ (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PD note: *please*, try to reduce your code to a **minimal** one when posting; it's a sign of respect for the time of people answering.

Comment: In Kaunas University of Technology (Lithuania) such design - component label with line - is widespread.